# Form validator ignores custom form required in Angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular4-forms

I have created 2 tags inside a form.

The first is an `input` tag and the second is a custom component with an `input` tag inside.

I need the form to validate them both obviously, so `form.valid` should stay `false` until both input have (valid) data.

I tried passing `ngDefaultControl` because I saw it in some examples and even put `required` in the instantiation of my custom component AND inside with no luck.

I saw other examples that demonstrate how to use custom components with `ngModel` by using `NG_VALIDATORS` and `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and what not but I was wondering if I can make it happen with my own 2 way data binding and not using `[(ngModel)]` from the outside.

Attached is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OzW3CWG4JmIme6myFFCg?p=preview).

Comment: I would suggest a reactive form, I have found that templatedriven forms are tricky in this case :)

Comment: Seems so, waiting to see if there's a solution before refactoring

Comment: Just as a comment, my answer there will only work with **one** input field in child, so if you want more, that won't work anymore.

Comment: I have tried to also add `ngModel` to `custom-input`, according to your example and it still isn't working. Can you have a look?
https://plnkr.co/edit/OzW3CWG4JmIme6myFFCg?p=preview

Comment: You need to have (both) `name` attribute and `ngModel` on the child tag :) https://plnkr.co/edit/dSTUlwVwKf50cs3uwxIW?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot @AJT_82 - that worked!

BTW - why did you say that `my answer there will only work with one input field in child`? I tried to add another input and validation still worked. Can you give me an example for cases where it will not work?

Comment: You cannot set another field in same child tag, that's what I mean. You can make many child components with one field though. If you found a way to do many fields in same tag, I'm curious to see :)

Comment: BTW, you could accept the duplicate since this happened to be one :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151164/discussion-between-mrgoos-and-ajt-82).